# Can you have an optional QueryParam in jersey?

Tags: java, jersey

Using java jersey, I have the following @QueryParam's in my method handler:

```
@Path("/hello")
handleTestRequest(@QueryParam String name, @QueryParam Integer age)
```

I know if I do:
http://myaddress/hello?name=something

It will go into that method....

I want to make it so that I can call:

> http://myaddress/hello?name=something

And it will also go into that same method. Is there any way I can flag an "optional" PathParam? Does it work with @FormParam too? Or am I required to create a separate method with a different method signature?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In JAX-RS parameters are not mandatory, so if you do not supply an age value, it will be `NULL`, and your method will still be called.

You can also use `@DefaultValue` to provide a default age value when it's not present.

The `@PathParam` parameter and the other parameter-based annotations, `@MatrixParam`, `@HeaderParam`, `@CookieParam`, and `@FormParam` obey the same rules as `@QueryParam`.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5np/index.html)

Comment: Looks like jersey 2.23 returns 404 by default in case a queryParameter is not passed. So is it not exactly following the spec?

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to add the `@DefaultValue` annotation the `age` parameter, so that if `age` isn't supplied, the default value will be used.

```
@Path("/hello")
handleTestRequest(
    @QueryParam("name") String name,
    @DefaultValue("-1") @QueryParam("age") Integer age)
```

According to the [Javadocs for `@DefaultValue`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html), it should work on all *Param annotations.

> Defines the default value of request meta-data that is bound using one of the following annotations: PathParam, QueryParam, MatrixParam, CookieParam, FormParam, or HeaderParam. The default value is used if the corresponding meta-data is not present in the request.

Answer (score 3):

You can always wrap return type in optional, for example: `@QueryParam("from") Optional<String> from`

Comment: Such solution does not work for me. Got ModelValidationException in the result

Comment: This doesn't work out-of-the-box, you have to find some code to support Optionals: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65148523/5209935