# Get Jersey to work with Optional parameters

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to get Jersey to work with Optional parameters. I have a very simple web service:

```java
    @Path("helloworld")
    public static class HelloWorldResource {
        public static final String CLICHED_MESSAGE = "Hello World!";

        @GET
        @Produces("text/plain")
        public String getHello(@QueryParam("maybe") Optional<String> maybe) {
            return CLICHED_MESSAGE;
        }
    }
```

And a simple harness:

```java
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldResource.class);

        String baseUri = "http://localhost:8080/api/";
        HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory
                .createHttpServer(URI.create(baseUri), config, false);
        server.start();
    }
```

However I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String com.mercuria.odyssey.server.GrizllyOptional$HelloWorldResource.getHello(java.util.Optional) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[text/plain], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.mercuria.odyssey.server.GrizllyOptional$HelloWorldResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@a3d9978]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.String com.mercuria.odyssey.server.GrizllyOptional$HelloWorldResource.getHello(java.util.Optional), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.util.Optional, source=maybe, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:337)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:140)
    at com.mercuria.odyssey.server.GrizllyOptional.main(GrizllyOptional.java:33)
```

I presume I need to do something about so that Jersey knows how to handle `Optional` parameters, but I've no idea what!

Comment: Is the purpose of Optional just to have the api work with and without the query param? If that is the case, the query param just has to be of type String. If you do not pass a value, "maybe" will be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So parameter types that are allowed as a `@xxxParam`, you need to meet one of these requirements:

- Be a primitive type
- Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
- Have a static method named `valueOf()` or `fromString()` that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
- Have a registered implementation of `ParamConverterProvider` JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a `ParamConverter` instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.
- Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2, 3 or 4 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

So in this case of `Optional`, going down the list; it's not a primitive; it doesn't have a String constructor; it doesn't have a static `valueOf()` or `fromString()`

So basically, the only option left is to implement a `ParamConverter`/`ParamConverterProvider` pair for it. Dropwizard (a framework built on top of Jersey) has a [good implementation for it](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/blob/master/dropwizard-java8/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/java8/jersey/OptionalParamConverterProvider.java). I will post it here in case the link ever goes dead

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.ClassTypePair;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

@Singleton
public class OptionalParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {
    private final ServiceLocator locator;

    @Inject
    public OptionalParamConverterProvider(final ServiceLocator locator) {
        this.locator = locator;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(final Class<T> rawType, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (Optional.class.equals(rawType)) {
            final List<ClassTypePair> ctps = ReflectionHelper.getTypeArgumentAndClass(genericType);
            final ClassTypePair ctp = (ctps.size() == 1) ? ctps.get(0) : null;

            if (ctp == null || ctp.rawClass() == String.class) {
                return new ParamConverter<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public T fromString(final String value) {
                        return rawType.cast(Optional.ofNullable(value));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String toString(final T value) {
                        return value.toString();
                    }
                };
            }

            final Set<ParamConverterProvider> converterProviders = Providers.getProviders(locator, ParamConverterProvider.class);
            for (ParamConverterProvider provider : converterProviders) {
                final ParamConverter<?> converter = provider.getConverter(ctp.rawClass(), ctp.type(), annotations);
                if (converter != null) {
                    return new ParamConverter<T>() {
                        @Override
                        public T fromString(final String value) {
                            return rawType.cast(Optional.ofNullable(value).map(s -> converter.fromString(value)));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String toString(final T value) {
                            return value.toString();
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Note, if you are using a Jersey version 2.26+, instead of injecting `ServiceLocator` you will use `InjectionManager` instead. Also the argument that accepts a `locator`, you will need to change the the manager.

With this class, you just need to register it with your Jersey application.

Comment: Thanks! Where do those requirements come from?

Seems that if `List<X>` is supported out-of-the-box then `Optional<X>` could also be supported (assuming `X` conforms etc). I guess it's one of those things.

Comment: Not sure how List has and equivalency to Optional. You're saying the because List works, you image Optional should work, right? I don't get that connection.

Comment: The requirements come from the JAX-RS spec, but you will see this same list in the javadoc for any of the `@XxxParam` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution, but it seems like DropWizard has a feature specifically to support this:

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/optional/OptionalParamBinder.java

So you can simply use their code:

```java
    import io.dropwizard.jersey.optional.*;

    class DirtyBinder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(OptionalParamConverterProvider.class).to(ParamConverterProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
            bind(OptionalDoubleParamConverterProvider.class).to(ParamConverterProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
            bind(OptionalIntParamConverterProvider.class).to(ParamConverterProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
            bind(OptionalLongParamConverterProvider.class).to(ParamConverterProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
        }
    }
```

then just add:

```
config.register(new DirtyBinder());
```